# Control A Representation in Python/Scala

Tags: python, scala

In Python "^A" is represented by chr(1). This is what I use as a separator in myfiles. What is the equivalent in Scala.I am reading the file using scala. I want to know how to represent ^A in order to split the data i read from my files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^A` is usually used to represent the Start Of Header Character (SOH). It's ascii value is x01.

You can create this in code with `val c: Char = 1`, if it's more clear to you, or if you need it in a string literal you can use the unicode notation `'\u0001'`

Comment: and if you don't like implicit conversion (`Int => Char`), you can always do it explicitly `1.toChar`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks much!